# Deploying Discord Bot to Heroku and Github

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, discord.js

I'm having a trouble about deploying my own Discord bot to heroku. When I deploying it my bot still offline. I just came back about coding bots and deploying to heroku sorry!

In my bot.js this is what i put:

require("dotenv").config();

```
let ver = process.env.NODE_ENV;

client.once("ready", async () => {
  if (ver === "production") {
    client.user.setActivity(`in code land`, { type: "PLAYING" });
  } else {
    client.user.setActivity(`over ${client.guilds.cache.size} server(s)`, {
      type: "WATCHING",
      status: "IDLE",
    });
  }
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  console.log(`the prefix is ` + prefix);
});
```

and the bottom part of bot.js is:

```
client.login(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

in .env this is my code:

```
NODE_ENV = TOKEN
```

in package.json this is what I put in scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production&&npm start",
    "development": "set NODE_ENV=development&&npm start"
}
```

I made file named `Procfile` then put this code:
Note: I changed the code in `Procfile` `npm start` to `node bot.js`, bot still offline

```
workers: node bot.js
```

I followed the instruction in heroku and github using git but I really don't understand why It's not working. If I need to edit my post to send picture please tell me. Thanks!

Update: Dec 22, 2021:
I looked at Heroku Application Logs, Here's what it said:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Maybe this is the reason why my bot still offline?

Comment: What do you put in the NODE_ENV environment variable, and why do you use it as the token to login?

Comment: Try changing `workers: npm start` to `workers: node bot.js` in your Procfile.

Comment: @user15517071 What environment to be exact? Where can I find it? Is that the code in  `scripts` section?

@Toasty If I change the worker, should I change the `npm start` at `scripts` section too?

Comment: Note that heroku questions are rarely suited for the [tag:git] tag. Heroku uses Git as a transport layer for the programs; you push some commit and Heroku tries to compile and run your program, and spits error messages at you *through* Git, but Git has nothing to do with the errors. It's just a relay.

Comment: Ohh, okay sir thanks for the information @torek

Comment: I recieved an error from heroku the message is `Unexpected token '??='` What is this error?

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code where the exception occurs?

Comment: that seems like a node version issue, discord.js requires minimum version of node to be `v16.6.0` (idk whats the minimum version of node on herkou is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='` is to do with the default node version for heroku and the version deiscord.js runs on.

Heroku uses node 14 and discord.js uses node 16, where the syntax for `??` was introduced in node 15.
There is however a simple fix for this solution.

In your `package.json` file add:

```js
"engines": {
   "node": "16.7"
},
```

Heroku will now know to use node 16.7 and so it will have the syntax for `??` available as well as work correctly for discord.js